# What are the odds of getting a gift from a Pokestop or gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

This morning I did my normal bike ride from home to work, spinning 6-7 stops and 3 gyms. I obtained 3 gifts from the stops, 0 from the gyms. I know this is far from representative, but in general, what are (roughly) the odds to get a gift from a Pokestop or Gym? Does the defending team matter for this (for bonus items it does, for example)?

Other things that could be explained:

- Can 1 stop give you multiple gifts?
- If a stop gives me a gift, does it the same to everyone (like quests)
- Can I get multiple gifts from the same stop/gym?
- Any bonuses? (e.g. new stops, 10th different stop in a row)

Comment: My morning ride was about 10 stops, 2 gyms, 0 gifts.

Comment: I did obtain (through a friend) a gift from a gym. That is good, because I live within reach of a gym :)

Comment: @dly wow, I had a much different experience this morning. 3 stops, 1 gym, 2 gifts. Maybe just luck, but my initial impression was that they were being more generous than I expected

Comment: I also got multiple gifts from the same gym. Also confirmed :)

Comment: This seems to be varying a lot.. looking forward to my next walk.

Comment: Note, you cannot hold more than 10 gifts at a time, so if you're at the max you won't receive any more gifts until you give some out.

Answer (score 2):

From my observations of playing the game and spinning at least 2 Pokespots most days, as well as talking to my friends', the chance of receiving a gift appears to be about a 30% or 33% chance of receiving a gift when spinning a Pokespot or Gym. This chance appears to be identical for both Pokespots and Gyms.

Answering your other questions, also based on my observations:

- You can only receive at most 1 gift per spin
- You can obtain another gift from the same Pokespot when you spin it again at the normal rate
- Defending team for a gym makes no difference
- If a Pokespot gives or doesn't give a gift to you, that doesn't affect the chance of another person receiving it
- No bonuses for receiving multiple gifts in a row